# WPF creating multiple groups of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls

Let's say I have five textboxes and five checkboxes next to them.

Now I want to create x groups of controls like that, then bind it with a list of objects that will contain text from textboxes and data on if checkboxes were checked.

What's the common approach for things like that?

I started with writing a function that would loop x times creating new RowDefinition inside an existing Grid, then inside that Row, make another Grid, inside that Grid create five rows and two columns, and add all those controls, set their rows, columns, add binding etc but I think it can't be the right way to do this, it's too much of a hassle writing all of that. There must be a better way.

Comment: Try DataTemplate and ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality using a ItemsControl and Defining Datatemplate for the Items. Refer the below code. I taken an example of 3 TextBoxes and Checkboxes.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itms">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Text1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Check1}" Content="Check1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Text2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Check2}" Content="Check2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Text3}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Check3}" Content="Check3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Add Items"></Button>
</StackPanel>

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> lst = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        itms.ItemsSource = lst;

    }
    int i = 0;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        lst.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = i.ToString(), Text2 =i.ToString()+1,Text3=i.ToString()+2,Check1=true,Check2=true,Check3=false});
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }
    public bool Check1 { get; set; }
    public bool Check2 { get; set; }
    public bool Check3 { get; set; }
}
```